# Saxon Unexpected token " < e o f >"

Tags: xquery, saxon

I am evaluating Stylus Studio mainly for xquery development against XML payload exchanged using SOAP.
I've inherited a complex xquery (about 1800 lines) and when I try to execute it using Saxon as engine I get this error:

XPST0003: Xquery sintax error in ##:Unexpected token " < e o f >" in path expression.

This query works fine in AcquaLogic, so no really sure it's a bug in the file or Saxon.
Could anyone please give advise on this? At least to understand on which line it finds this token.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated: Be sure to include oXygen XML Editor in your evaluation. I highly recommend it. (http://www.oxygenxml.com/)

Comment: Publish your source and many people will be able to explain the error. Generally this means that the input to the XQuery processor (or a separate sub-expression) is syntactically invalid -- some more input was expected in order to complete a grammar rule of the language.

Comment: Source code is about 1800, I don't really think anyone will go through that.
However I've given a try to Oxygen, well it's much easier and efficient. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

`<EOF>` means that Saxon encountered a literal "End of File" byte.  Perhaps your path expression is corrupted?  Other tools might ignore the EOF if they know the buffer is longer, but on that path lies madness.

Comment: what's the best way to locate it and fix it?